# HTML5 Charset Character Encoding Declaration: Need to use Spanish characters?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I am coding a site in Spanish and need to use the actual characters "ó" or "é", for example, rather than using the character codes (`&oacute;` or `&eacute;`). I'm quite sure I've followed the HTML5 spec "to a T" but firefox and safari are still replacing the characters with an `&mdash;`

Here's the relevant tags I'm using in the head:

```
    <html lang="es"> 
    <meta charset=ISO-8859-1>
```

I get the following error/warning from the W3c Validator:

> Using windows-1252 instead of the declared encoding iso-8859-1.
>
> `<meta charset=ISO-8859-1>`

I also have firefox set to spanish as the primary language.

***How do I get spanish accented characters to display with HTML5?***

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if it helps: O-acute and E-acute are in the same place in both 8859-1 and windows-1252. So that's not the problem.

Comment: UTF-8 gives me the black diamond with a question mark inside.

Comment: You need to make sure that the file is actually encoded in the encoding you're specifying in `<meta charset>`. This has nothing to do with HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As deceze commented above, this has nothing to do with HTML5, and should be done in UTF-8.

I use Panic Coda to code, and I needed to convert the document to UTF-8. Problem Solved! Text>Encoding>UTF-8